# Which tests are used to calculate the individual P-values in the Stata logit command (binary logistic regression)?

Tags: regression, logistic, p-value, stata

This picture is from page 1290 in the Stata manual:
[image: Page 1290, Stata manual]

The model can be made with the following code in Stata:

```
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r16/auto

keep make mpg weight foreign

logit foreign weight mpg
```

As I understand the overall fit for the model is calculated with a chi2 test (Prob > chi2 = 0.0000), but how are the individual P-values (P>|z|) calculated?

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Can you elaborate a little bit? Could I write in my manuscript that the individual P-values are calculated with a z-test as I would write other P-values are calculated with a students t-test or a Pearson's chi2 test. Any references would be great.

Comment: The answer I was looking for was the one you can read below, but thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tests shown by Stata for the individual coefficients are **Wald tests** whose test statistics have the form
$$
W_j = \frac{\hat{\beta}_j}{\widehat{\operatorname{SE}}(\hat{\beta}_j)}\sim N(0,1)
$$

Under the hypothesis than an individual coefficient is zero, these statistics will asymptotically follow the standard normal distribution. Hence, they are $z$-values. The corresponding $p$-values are calculated from the standard normal cdf $\Phi(x)$. Specifically, for two-sided $p$-values: $p=2\cdot\Phi(-|z|)$. For example in Stata for the coefficient for `mpg`:

```
di 2*normal(-abs(1.83))
.06724994
```

**Reference**

Hosmer DW, Lemeshow S, Sturdivant RX (2013): Applied Logistic Regression. 3rd ed. Wiley.